# Missing locale data for locale: "undefined". Using default locale: "en" as fallback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I develop a react app which shows the error

[React Intl] Missing locale data for locale: "undefined". Using default locale: "en" as fallback.

my app.js

```
import{ IntlProvider,addLocaleData } from "react-intl";
import messages from "./messages";
import{locale} from "./reducers/locale";
import {setLocale} from "./actions/locale"; 

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  const { location, isAuthenticated, loaded, lang } = this.props;
  console.log(lang);//undefined in console
  return (
    <IntlProvider key={ lang } locale={lang} messages={messages}>
     </IntlProvider>

    );
  }
```

Comment: If you want to render with fallback you could do something like `key={ lang || 'en'} locale={lang || 'en'}`. If you don't want to render if lang is undefined, then return null

Comment: thanks @Kunukn I tried but it wont work

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a console.log, on the parent component to verify the data you are passing through first?. If it's undefined on this component it's most likely you are passing it an undefined value form the parent.

Comment: Parent component ??

Comment: import{ LOCALE_SET } from "../types";




    export const localeSet = lang =>({


    type: LOCALE_SET,


    lang


  });


   export const setLocale = lang => dispatch =>{


    localStorage.alhubLang = lang;
    dispatch(localeSet(lang));
    console.log(lang); // this prints the specified language
    
   }; `

Answer (score 1):

Before your component is mounted, you may get undefined and rendering element with undefined will throw you the error.

Return the element only if not undefined:

```
if(lang && messages) {
  return (
    <IntlProvider key={ lang } locale={lang} messages={messages}>
    </IntlProvider>
  )
} else {
  return null
}
```

Shorthand:

```
return lang && messages &&
  <IntlProvider key={ lang } locale={lang} messages={messages}> 
  </IntlProvider> || 
  null
```

Now, this will ensure the element to render only if lang is defined (which is came after component is mounted) and you'll see no error. This renders `null` at first render and after you get the value, it will render the element.

---

Yes, obviously, if you want to render the element without the lang and messages at first load, you may use:

```
return <IntlProvider 
   key={ lang || 'en' } {/* en as default */}
   locale={lang || 'en'} 
   messages={messages || ''}> 
  </IntlProvider>
```

Comment: [React Intl] Missing message: "nav.dashboard" for locale: "en"

[React Intl] Cannot format message: "nav.dashboard", using message id as fallback

Comment: Do the same with message. Updated the post.

Comment: thanks, @Bhojendra Rauniyar

messages is   is printing correctly
but this is not working peoprely
<FormattedMessage id="nav.dashboard"
      default message="dash"/>

nav.dashboard is displayed